# Join table on one-to-many cannot update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Ok, check this weirdness out. I have two types of users, leaders and followers (who each have their own subclasses for reasons that please for the love of god I don't want to go into and moreover are not germaine to this discussion).

```
class Admin < Account
  has_many :leader_follower_relationships, foreign_key: :leader_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :leader_follower_relationships
end

class Follower < Account
  has_one :follower_leader_relationship, class_name: "LeaderfollwerRelationship",
      dependent: :destroy
  has_one :leader, through: :follower_leader_relationship
end

class LeaderFollowerRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "Follower", foreign_key: :artist_id
  belongs_to :leader, class_name: "Admin", foreign_key: :leader_id
end
```

Anyway, I can establish the relationship using a has_one, but I can't update it:

```
follower1.leader = leader1
  (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Account Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."auth_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Account Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."email_address" = 'leader1@example.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms) ...
  (0.5ms)  COMMIT

follower1.leader = leader2
  (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  (1.8ms)  UPDATE "leader_follower_relationships" SET "leader_id" = 3 WHERE     "leader_follower_relationships"."" IS NULL
  (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at     or near """"
  LINE 1: ...ader_id" = 3 WHERE "leader_follower_relationships"."" IS NULL
```

If my follower can have many leaders (using has_many), I can both create and update:

```
class Follower < Account
  has_many :follower_leader_relationships, class_name: "LeaderfollwerRelationship",
      dependent: :destroy
  has_many :leaders, through: :follower_leader_relationships
end
```

These commands work in succession:

```
follower1.leaders = [leader1]
follower1.leaders = [leader2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ActiveRecord` error makes me think that the table for your `LeaderFollowerRelationship` model does not have an `id` column.  If that's not it, can you post the related bits of `schema.rb`?

Comment: Jeremy, I think you're spot on. However, I read somewhere that join tables should not have `id`s on them. (Although looking back that my just be for has_and_belongs_to_many.)

Comment: Now I'm just curious as to why many-to-many would work without an `id` but not one-to-many.

Comment: Yeah, it's only for habtm that you don't need ids on the table.  When you have an intermediate model you need the ids.  I have no idea why many-to-many would work but not one-to-many...